# I have to type pass every action in datagrip with oracle, even if i check to remember it in "Project Data Sources" (crtl+alt+shift+S in DataGrip)

Tags: oracle, archlinux, datagrip

[image: my problem]
[image: my problem2]

I have to type my pass every action even if I check to remember it.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

I expect to dont write this pass every single time

Comment: In DataGrip 2019.1 remember password options are completely re-worked. Please, try DataGrip 2019.1 and report.

Comment: i updated and its same https://i.imgur.com/dNXMdlb.png @moscas

Comment: Well, screenshot looks like there are problems in credentials :)